# How to convert text to json file Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, type-conversion

I have text like this:

Date    SKU Type of transaction           Type of payment           Payment details     Montant

27 févr. 20 Autres  Autres      Solde du montant de la réserve précédente     €4 702,71

Is there some way to convert this to json in node js.

Expected:

```
[ { "date": "27 févr. 20", "Type of transaction": "Autres", "Type of payment": "Solde du montant de la réserve précédente", "Payment details": "€4 702,71" } ]
```

Thank everyone.

Comment: can u add code. expected output

Comment: [
{
"date": "27 févr. 20",
"Type of transaction": "Autres",
"Type of payment": "Solde du montant de la réserve précédente",
"Payment details": "€4 702,71"
}
]

expected output

Comment: is this CSV file ??

Comment: Since the text is not delimited by any character like "," or "space", it can't be grouped under keys. One thing you can do it add a delimiter character manually and then convert it using packages like CSV to JSON converter. Hope it helps

Comment: yeah! use https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson

Comment: No its not csv, okay I will try to add delimiter thanks.